# Excel crashes when loading file that contains userform

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

**Excel crashes when opening files that contain a userform**

This is a known problem with a known <strike>solution</strike> workaround which is to delete a file called `Excel.box` from here:

`C:\Users\SlowLearner\Application Data\Microsoft\Forms\Excel.box`

According to [this forum post](https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/32615-Winword-box-(Word-2000-SR1)?p=167660&viewfull=1#post167660) the purpose of the Excel.box (& Word.box) file is:

> Files such as Winword.box and Excel.box are associated with the
>   Control Toolbox you see when you are designing a UserForm in the
>   Visual Basic editor. The files contain information about the layout of
>   the Control Toolbox (additional tab pages, controls that have been
>   added or removed, custom icons, ...) If a user has never modified the
>   Control Toolbox in any way, there will probably be no .box file. By
>   deleting a .box file, you will restore the Control Toolbox to its
>   default (factory preset) configuration - this is the only way to do
>   that. Sometimes, the .box file becomes corrupted and must be deleted.
>   There are no negative side effects to deleting it.

**Unfortunately Excel.box returns :(**

It would seem that for most users the problem is fixed by deleting the file, sadly not for me.

I'd like to understand what is causing this problem to recur. A few points to note:

- this (touch wood) is not impacting MS Word on my PC
- I am using Office 2010, 64 bit version on Win10
- I have not made any *conscious* change to form settings
- if I delete the file > start Excel > UN-DELETE the file: everything works :-/
- some [other experiences with this issue here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfoffice/office-2016-crashes-when-userform-added-to-vba/f2f16ffa-9a1f-4bfd-babb-1e93a78d5c65?auth=1)

For the time being I'll just check for and delete the file before launching Excel, but this is hardly an acceptable solution for the long term. Appreciate thoughts for a proper fix...  TIA

---

Additional Information:

I have not fully explored the crash but so far it happens when:

- starting the application by opening an xl?.m file with a userform

  - application does not get past the splash screen
  - crashes with the application's CRASH screen (... encounted an error...)
- starting the application with a blank worksheet then adding a userform

  - crashes immediately with the applications CRASH screen displayed (see below)

[image: Crash when adding a userform to blank spreadsheet]

The above crash happened after rebooting my PC, had a chance to explore it some more.

- First I opened the file I had been working on (contains userforms):

  - annoyingly it opened without crashing
  - I did NOT enter the IDE
  - I closed the file (Excel closed normally)
- Then I created a new worksheet

  - I opened the VBA IDE
  - right-click 'add UserForm' - ***Excel crashed immediately***
  - *(I aborted the recovery / search for a solution attempt)*
- Then I re-opened the file I had been working on

  - opened the VBA IDE (the project is PW protected)
  - the very instant that I entered the PW and hit enter Excel crashed
  - crash was same both times...

---

Safe Mode:

Crash still happens in safe mode - steps to reproduce:

- Run: Excel /safe
- Open VBA IDE
- r-click add userform
- crashes immediately

---

Creation of the EXCEL.box file

Based on visually observing the folder which had the Excel.box file I did some tests to try and see when it was created.  Basically it seems to appear when one of the following happens:
 - the UserForm tools box is closed
 - the IDE is closed (after showing the userform)

I've also now tried to modify the userform toolbox by removing everything from it. Excel is still crashing after every restart of the application *(which is odd as I was not able to crash it like that earlier)*.

---

Office Repair - not tested (yet)

Reluctant to try Office Repair as based on the following quote from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfoffice/office-2016-crashes-when-userform-added-to-vba/f2f16ffa-9a1f-4bfd-babb-1e93a78d5c65?auth=1) (scroll down: pg 1 reply 8 by Steve IT)  I'm not expecting it to work :-/ (but will try if no other suggestions surface).

> Thanks for the continued suggestions, however I have tried a repair and also removed Visual Studio 2013 and Office altogether (just in case VS was interfering) and reinstalled both, but it still throws the errors reported previously.

---

Other user profiles

Created a brand new user called 'test'. Test has the exact same problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug have added extra info. Now, perversely, I am unable reproduce the crash so will reboot and see what happens :-/

Comment: @Mat'sMug - crashed after reboot, see update.

Comment: Does it crash when Excel is launched in Safe mode (`Excel.exe /safe`)?

Comment: @PatricK yup, have updated. Was expecting it to crash based on the research I had already done, but it is now confirmed. Cheers

Comment: Repair Office install is my next step, could also be some corrupted dll/ocx files.

Comment: @PatricK - not ruling it out but... see update.

Comment: Tested from logging in a new/different user on the machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157249/discussion-between-slowlearner-and-patrick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem eventually resolved itself, not sure why.  I continued to use Excel normally and it continued to crash so I would delete the offending .box file and start over...

As of Nov 2017 Excel no longer crashes with respect to this issue; my best guess is there was an automatic update that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue still occurs and it is not just limited to Excel but also Powerpoint.

The fix as mentioned above works where you move / delete any files in the below folder location resolves the issue.

```
    C:\Users\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Forms
```

It is highly likely that this error is caused by bad code in a macro or an Add-In that uses forms. The problem is replicating this can be difficult so you have to debug this in some way when it does crash out.

```
    POWERPNT.box
    EXCEL.box
```

are some of the files that get generated, where Excel or Powerpoint crash on the splash screen.

Comment: I don't think this is caused by bad code _in the VBA project_. None of my code was changed and the issue fixed itself. Actually, the code was working when it was last saved and something happened in the interim. Also it was confined to a single PC, other PCs ran the same code without issue. It could be caused by the project becoming corrupted... but I think I ruled that out at the time too....

Comment: I don't necessarily point to bad code in the project as such, just in some Add-Ins that may also be loaded. I have seen stuff such as debug versions of add-ins with break points in there and sort of had a (facepalm) moment.

Comment: Sure, but I can tell you that, in my case at least, there were no additional addins loaded for Excel, I basically don't use it - mostly use Word. As far as my Excel is concerned NOTHING changed. My VBA IDE Add-ins are: MZ Tools (latest ver) & Rubberduck both of which are excellent and apply to all VBA IDEs. All I can tell you is the code did not change, the IDE addins may have but I'm reasonably sure they did not cause the issue. I also ruled out buggy code because the issue happened with ONLY a NEW worksheet open. I dislike not knowing what the cause is, but... it ONLY impacted Excel so ??

Comment: @SlowLearner what antivirus do you use? I find there maybe some interactions going on with this that maybe impacting this as well.

Comment: Trend Micro - but I don't think it was involved because it would crash when adding a UF to a blank document... but... hey?

Comment: Yea...check the Heuristics level or any particular Office specific checks. I have seen some stuff that can seriously interfere without you even realising it.

Comment: Well if it happens again, at least I've got a new angle. What AV are you using?

Comment: We are using Bromium which is like a next gen AV.

Comment: Hi Add too quickly. You should have a look at how it works. Really good as an AV

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the command

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm").Activate
```

just before your
"UserForm".Show line.